# I'm developing a server and ip passed as parameter not working

Tags: c++, sockets, argv, htonl, inet-aton

I'm using:

```
struct in_addr ip;                                         
#define HOST_PORT atoi(argv[2])
#define HOST_IP inet_aton(argv[1], &ip)

sockaddr_in sockaddr;
sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(HOST_IP);
sockaddr.sin_port = htons(HOST_PORT);
```

To get the ip and port numbers in cli.
Then i bind, listen, accept and read.

I do compile and when i use *./server localhost 8080* everything is working as intended.

But if i use *./server 127.0.0.1 8080* or *./server 192.168.30.1 8080* seems like is bind and listening, no errors but i don't recive the request.

Comment: Are you sure that `inet_aton(argv[1], &ip)` returns 1 if `argv[1]` equals `localhost`? It shouldn't and it doens't on my machine (returns `0` as expected). Indeed, according to man pages, this function works only with "IPv4  numbers-and-dots  notation".

Comment: Yes, in my case it does work using localhost but not using ipv4 addresses.

Comment: @StringManolo You really should be using `getaddrinfo()` instead, eg: `struct addrinfo hints, *res; memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints)); hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP; if (getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &res) == 0) { /* use res->ai_addr and res->ai_addrlen as needed ... */ freeaddrinfo(res); }`  It will parse IP address strings and hostname strings into `sockaddr` structs for you, and will happily handle strings related to the local host like `"localhost"`, `"127.0.0.1"`, `"192.168.30.1"`, etc.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau i'm asking about a problem with a bike, what's the reason why this happens. So i can learn from it and solve my problem. Solutions like: Buy a truck here is a catalog... Are not what i need. getaddrinfo do way more things. It's not even intended for this job. I'm more interested in what is the mistake i made than a working solution. There are thousands of working servers around i can copy and paste.

Comment: @StringManolo "*It's not even intended for this job*" - actually it is. This is exactly the type of scenario that its `AI_PASSIVE` flag is meant for - to parse input into appropriate `sockaddr_...` structs that are suitable to give to `bind()` for a `listen()`'ing server. But whatever. I have now posted an answer for why your code is not working.

Comment: @Amessihel i only had to knew i need to use ip.s_addr instead of using ip directly. xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You are misusing `inet_aton()`.

You are assigning the *return value* of `inet_aton()` to your `sockaddr` variable, rather than assigning the `in_addr` struct that `inet_aton()` outputs.  *The return value is NOT an IP address*!

`inet_aton()` *returns* a non-zero value on success, and 0 on failure.  In other words, its *return value* is basically a boolean value.

Calling `bind()` with an IP address of `0.0.0.0` (aka `INADDR_ANY`) instructs it to bind an `AF_INET` socket to all local network interfaces on the specified port, which is very common (and generally preferred) for a server to do.

Calling `inet_aton("localhost")` **fails** because you can't pass a hostname to `inet_aton()`, so it *returns* 0, and then you `bind()` the socket using a `sockaddr_in` whose `s_addr` is set to `INADDR_ANY`, which is OK, so your code *seems* to work with `"localhost"`, but only as a fluke.

Calling `inet_aton("127.0.0.1")` or `inet_aton("192.168.30.1")` **succeeds**, so it *returns* non-zero, and then you `bind()` the socket using a `sockaddr_in` whose `s_addr` is set to an invalid IP, causing `bind()` to either fail outright, or worse to bind to an existing network interface that is different than the one you are expecting.

Also, the `in_addr` that `inet_aton()` outputs is already in network byte order, so there is no need to call `htonl()` on its output.

Try this instead:

```c
struct in_addr ip;
#define HOST_PORT atoi(argv[2])
#define HOST_IP ((inet_aton(argv[1], &ip) != 0) ? ip.s_addr : 0)

struct sockaddr_in sockaddr;
memset(&sockaddr, 0, sizeof(sockaddr));
sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = HOST_IP;
sockaddr.sin_port = htons(HOST_PORT);

// use sockaddr as needed ...
```

Or, simply get rid of your `HOST_IP` and `HOST_PORT` macros, as they are not really helping you:

```c
struct sockaddr_in sockaddr;

memset(&sockaddr, 0, sizeof(sockaddr));
sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
inet_aton(argv[1], &(sockaddr.sin_addr));
sockaddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));

// use sockaddr as needed ...
```

---

That being said, you really should be using `getaddrinfo()` instead, eg:

```c
struct addrinfo hints, *res;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

if (getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &res) == 0)
{
    // use res->ai_addr and res->ai_addrlen with socket() and bind() as needed ...
    freeaddrinfo(res);
}
```

`getaddrinfo()` will parse both IP address strings and hostname strings into appropriate `sockaddr_...` structs for you, and will happily handle strings that are related to the local host, like `"localhost"`, `"127.0.0.1"`, `"192.168.30.1"`, etc.

Comment: this is exactly the answer i needed.